# Using pgpl /copy command in Unix script

Tags: postgresql, psql

Postgres 11
Unix/Linux OS

I would like to copy a file from one server to a server and then use the pgpl copy command to upload that same file to a few different servers in different environments (Dev/QA/Prod).

I have the copy working and the upload script working with the exception that it wants me to input the password.

my script looks something like this.

```
PGPASSWORD=MyPassword

psql dbname -h 123.45.678.90 -U LoginID -c "\COPY dbname.schema ($COLUMNS) FROM '$CSV' delimiter ',' csv header;"
```

I have tried with and without PGPASSWORD and I also have the user id and password setup in the .pgpass file.  Is there a way to not have it ask for a password?

Comment: Both `PGPASSWORD` and a password file will work if you do it right (and use the correct password). To figure out where you are going wrong, you'd have to describe your setup in more detail and show more of your script.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `export PGPASSWORD=MyPassword`?